# Angular 2 XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição POST para uma API e estou recebendo este erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://*. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

No entanto, quando faço uma requisição GET ela funciona.

Meu método get:

```
getPerfis() {
    return this.http.get<PerfilModel[]>(globals.BASE_URL + 'perfis');
}
```

meu método post:

```
updateFirstAccess(alterarSenha: AlterarSenhaModel) {
    let h = new Headers();
    h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http2.post(globals.BASE_URL + 'usuarios/senhas/redefinicoes/' + 
      alterarSenha.chave, JSON.stringify(alterarSenha), { headers: h }
    ).map(res => res.json);
}
```

ps: o plugin cors toggle está ativado.